# Image maps + lightbox wordpress plugin?

Tags: images, wordpress

So I am looking for a wordpress plugin for showing an image map with lightbox functionality. All I need is the image map with some links and when you click the link/pin/icon, it will pop a lightbox with an image.

I would love to try learning how to code something so "simple" but I'm in a hurry so any plugin will do (or anyone that can code it quick lol)

Thanks!

*In the worst case, any guide on adding the built in lightbox to a link will work*

Comment: "In the worst case, any guide on adding the built in lightbox to a link will work" I don't know how you went with this, but if you have a go at this first you could post on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) if you run into difficulty, since providing programming help is out of the scope of Software Recommendations